# Why can't I run my hello swing app?

Tags: java, swing

I compile with javac helloswing.java but cannot run with java swingtutorial.helloswing as it said Exception in thread main NoClassDefFoundError. Could not find main class

I just added classpath to c:...\rt.jar but still java -cp . swingtutorial.helloswing cannot find main why ?

```
package swingtutorial;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class helloswing extends JFrame {

    public helloswing() {
       setTitle("Hello Swing");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                helloswing ex = new helloswing();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Class names should be `EachWordUpperCase`.  So this class name should be `HelloSwing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath. Try with

```
javac swingtutorial\helloswing.java
java -cp . swingtutorial.helloswing
```

Comment: java -cp . swingtutorial.helloswing it says now that it cannot find main

Comment: I've updated my answer. The location of the class file is important. Also it is important that the classpath points to the root directory where your class files are located.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the fully qualified name of the class:

```
   java swingtutorial.helloswing
```

Comment: I tried now it said Exception in thread main NoClassDefFoundError. Could not find main class

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run

```
java swingtutorial.helloswing -cp [classpath]
```

Since the package is `swingtutorial`, you need to specify that in the name of the class to run.

Comment: what do you mean by [classpath] ?

Comment: OK I added rt.jar to classpath but still cannot find main

Comment: classpath is the location of your compiled classes. You don't need to explicitly add rt.jar - java.exe does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the *classpath* concept in Java better before you can solve this problem on your own.

I would suggest having a look on the official Java tutorial section on this:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Comment: I just added classpath to c:\...\rt.jar but still java -cp . swingtutorial.helloswing cannot find main why ?